# Is there a way to write a HTML form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to RoR and I've stumbled upon a problem. I'm trying to approve or deny a rent, and have been successful in doing so using the HTML form.

```rb
<form action="<%= approve_rental_url(rental) %>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Approve">
</form>
```

This code works without a problem and I know that it isn't the rails way of doing it. I've tried to write it in the rails way and have encountered a problem which says **No route matches [POST] "/cats/2"**.

```rb
#Ruby code

<%= form_for approve_rental_url(rental) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the `rails routes`

```rb
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
approve_rental POST   /rentals/:id/approve(.:format)    rentals#approve                                                   
   deny_rental POST   /rentals/:id/deny(.:format)       rentals#deny                                                     
       rentals POST   /rentals(.:format)                rentals#create                                                       
    new_rental GET    /rentals/new(.:format)            rentals#new                                                       
          cats GET    /cats(.:format)                   cats#index                                                      
               POST   /cats(.:format)                   cats#create                                                       
       new_cat GET    /cats/new(.:format)               cats#new                                                       
      edit_cat GET    /cats/:id/edit(.:format)          cats#edit                                                       
           cat GET    /cats/:id(.:format)               cats#show                                                       
               PATCH  /cats/:id(.:format)               cats#update                                                       
               PUT    /cats/:id(.:format)               cats#update                                                       
          root GET    /                                 cats#index
```

Comment: the from is getting submitted to the action attached for this action `approve_rental_url(rental)`. can you please run `rake routes` and paste the output here.

Comment: I've edited the question. You can view the routes.

Comment: `No route matches [POST] "/cats/2"` is not caused by the code provided in the question. Look at the stack trace again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `form_for`, you have to pass record as argument [like this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for):

```
<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
  First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
  Last name : <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
  Biography : <%= f.text_area :biography %><br />
  Admin?    : <%= f.check_box :admin %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If you need to pass URL, you need to use [`form_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) instead of `form_for`:

```
form_tag('/posts/1', method: :put)
```

But these helpers are softly deprecated. Now there is [`form_with`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with) helper.

You can pass to it URL or record

```
form_with(model: nil, scope: nil, url: nil, format: nil, **options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since this is such a common problem, in rails you can just write

```
link_to 'Approve', approve_rental_url(rental), class: 'btn btn-success', method: :post
```

or use the `button_to` helper

```
button_to 'Approve', approve_rental_url(rental), class: 'btn btn-success'
```

(which will POST by default)
and both will automatically inline a form to perform the POST.